# aspnet users and aspnet membership tables data lost on Visual studio 2010 database project Deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have created a database project in my asp.net MVC 3 solution using Visual studio 2010. When I try to deploy it, all my tables and data is added as well in sql server 2008. Only asp.net users table and aspnet membership table data is not added in sql server only deploy using Visual studio 2010.

Please suggest me how can I assign permissions so that aspnet tables also get data. Right now, If I try to deploy, I get this error when deploy process reaches aspnet users and aspnet membership tables:

```
    Creating the aspnet_Applications table...
    Creating the aspnet_Users table...
    Creating the aspnet_SchemaVersions table...
    Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
    Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
    : 
(0 row(s) affected)

    : 
(1 row(s) affected)

    Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
    Creating the vw_aspnet_Applications view...
    Creating the vw_aspnet_Users view...
    Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
    Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
    ----------------------------------------
    Completed execution of InstallCommon.SQL
    ----------------------------------------
    -------------------------------------------
    Starting execution of InstallMembership.SQL
    -------------------------------------------
    Creating the aspnet_Membership table...
    Creating the vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers view...
    Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
    : 
(0 row(s) affected)
```